# Accidentally hit ctrl+alt+f12 and then ctrl+alt+f2 and rebooted

Tags: 20.10

This is my first time asking help on this forum.

I was messing around with keyboard shortcuts and accidentally hit ctrl+alt+f12. My screen turned black. Then i hit ctrl+alt+f2 to get to shell mode and rebooted the system. When the computer turned back on, the grub menu didn't show up like it always does, but instead there was a black screen.
My question is: How can i get it back to normal?
I am using Kubuntu 20.10 if that helps!
Help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are hitting one of the rough edges of Linux. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fx</kbd> keys move to different virtual consoles. On <kbd>F12</kbd>, no virtual console is set up, so you see just a blinking cursor.

On standard Ubuntu, your running desktop is on tty2. You can return to it hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> or simply <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> would bring you to the login manager GDM, running on tty1.

Kubuntu may still be set up the traditional way, because you indicate <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> gives you a console. Formerly, also on standard Ubuntu, the graphical session was running on <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>. So next time, try that combination: it should bring you back to your graphical desktop.

I called this a "linux rough edge" because this is obviously very obscure and highly confusing for new users. It is of course not anymore a problem once you know what that is and how it works.

Comment: When i first searched about my problem on the internet, i found the same suggestions that you wrote. But i had already force rebooted the computer, and even the grub menu didn't show up(i had the grub menu to show up for 3s). i forgot to mention, that the next day i installed kde neon on my computer, but thanks to your help. Now i know and i am sure someone else finds your suggestion useful.

Answer (score 0):

On newer UBUNTU flavors (18.04+) the way to come back to the GUI is Alt+F2 (or Ctrl+Alt+F2).
Alt+F1 (or Ctrl+Alt+F1) moves you to the login screen.

When back to the GUI it appears to be frozen for some seconds, mouse cursor moves but nothing happens. Just wait a while and all is good again soon.